# How to rescale the y-axis of a boxplot in python

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I have a boxplot below (using seaborn) where the "box" part is too squashed. How do I change the scale along the y-axis so that the boxplot is more presentable (ie. the "box" part is too squashed) but still keeping all the outliers in the plot?

[image: boxplot]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things here.

- Make the plot bigger
- Change the range of the y-axis

Since you want to keep the outliers, rescaling the y-axis may not be that effective. You haven't given any data or code examples. So I'll just add a way to make your figure bigger.

```py
# this script makes the figure bigger and rescale the y-axis
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It worked! I will remember to include a sample code next time.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the axis after the plot:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
a = sns.boxplot(y=df["sepal_length"])
a.set(ylim=(0,10))
```

Additionally, you could try dropping outliers from the plot passing `showfliers = False` in `boxplot`.